# How to use the HTML DOM FileUpload Object

Tags: file-upload

I would like to know how to use the HTML DOM FileUpload object in a client webpage to upload a file from the file system of the client computer to my embedded server. The HTML code to present the file selection dialog on the client webpage is easy and works great:

```
<input title="Click to choose an image file" type="file" id="fileselect_img" />
```

But once the file has been selected how is the transfer to my embedded server started and how is my server notified of the incomming data so I can write a function to receive it? I should mention that my embedded server is running on a small 32bit PowerPC processor with an RTOS that provides me with a limited http server. I can serve up web pages and perform cgi function calls but thats about it.

I require this in order to allow a client computer to upload a binary, firmware update file to my embedded server which it will use to update it's application code. Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions. ~Tim

~Tim